# How to get matching elements from multiple tree sets into one?

Tags: java, treeset

I have multiple tree sets that all have different values. I am trying to get the matching elements from every tree set and put it in one final tree set.

So what I am looking for is if

Tree Set one has  a b c d

Tree Set two has  b d e g

and Tree Set three has b e d h

my return tree set would have b and d

The code I have tried is

```
   TreeSet<String> uniqueWords = uniqueWords(words);
    TreeSet[] results = new TreeSet[uniqueWords.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (String word : uniqueWords) {
      // get will return a TreeSet
      results[i] = ((TreeSet)HashMap.get(word));
      if (results[i] == null) {
        return new TreeSet();
      }
      i++;
    }
    TreeSet finalList =  new ReferenceSet();;
    for (int step = 1; i < results.length; step++) {
      finalList.retainAll(results[step]);
    }
    return finalList;`
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the intersection of multiple sets which can be achieved with `Collection#retainAll` (as you already have in the question).  If you want the final `Set` to be separate (rather than be one of the three initial `Set`s), you can use the following:

```
SortedSet<String> intersection = new TreeSet<>(setA);

intersection.retainAll(setB);
intersection.retainAll(setC);
```

Here's an example:

```
var setA = new TreeSet<>(List.of("a", "b", "c", "d"));
var setB = new TreeSet<>(List.of("b", "d", "e", "g"));
var setC = new TreeSet<>(List.of("b", "e", "d", "h"));

var intersection = new TreeSet<>(setA);

intersection.retainAll(setB);
intersection.retainAll(setC);

System.out.println(intersection);
```

Output:

```
[b, d]
```